# FancyBox -- "allowScriptAccess" set to "Always"

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Can we change the "allowScriptAccess" value in the FancyBox library file and set it to something else instead of "Always"?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

You would rather prefer to change it on your custom fancybox initialization script for `SWF` content like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "swf",
        swf: {
            allowscriptaccess: 'samedomain' // or whatever
        }
    });
});
```

Read more about [allowscriptaccess](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/control-access-scripts-host-web.html)